# Query without "where" still process "where"

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

when running  this function :

```
function periksa_file(){    
    $this->db->select('f.id as id, k.id as kategori_id')->from('file as f')->join('kategori as k','f.id_kategori = k.id');
    return $this->db->get();
}
```

i get this error :

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1052

Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

SELECT `f`.`id` as `id`, `k`.`id` as `kategori_id` FROM `file` as `f` JOIN `kategori` as `k` ON `f`.`id_kategori` = `k`.`id` WHERE `id` = ''

Filename: C:/File/xampp/htdocs/sistemfiledigital/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

why there is a "where" clause even i don't call it?

Comment: You **do** have a WHERE clause `WHERE `id` = ''`

Comment: Are you sure that you are indeed loading the query in question and that you don't have anything cached and the file is saved?

Try to change your query to just the select one and see if it properly changes.

Comment: I've not used Codeigniter for some time but how about $this->db->join('file', 'kategori.id = file.id', 'inner');

Comment: @Nelles yes, but i did not call it in from the query that called with codeigniter, it just appears on the error report. Both tables have column with same name wich is 'id', if just the "where" clause not there it will be no problem. But somehow it generated automatically, is that some sort of injection prevention mechanism from the codeigniter itself or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the "where" clause came from another faraway call, so I need to put

```
$this->db->reset_query()
```

before calling select.